# toggle between multiple lines in morris chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toggle, morris.js

I am using morris charts along with angular js. I am drawing three lines for different values. I want to use three checkboxes, so that the line is displayed only when the corresponding checkbox is checked. The unchecked lines should hide from the chart.
Here is the div container for chart:-

```
 <div
                    line-chart
                    line-data='yearly_total'
                    line-xkey='y'
                    line-ykeys='["a", "b","c"]'
                    line-labels='["A", "B","C"]'
                    line-colors='["Blue", "Green","red"]'

                    >
               </div>
```

This is the example of my json object that i am using:-

```
    [
    { "y": "1.", "a": 100, "b": 90,"c":30 },
    { "y": "2.", "a": 75,  "b": 65 ,"c":50},
    { "y": "3.", "a": 50,  "b": 40 ,"c":20},
    { "y": "4.", "a": 75,  "b": 65 ,"c":50},
    { "y": "5.", "a": 50,  "b": 40 ,"c":60},
    { "y": "6.", "a": 75,  "b": 65 ,"c":40},
    { "y": "7.", "a": 100, "b": 90 ,"c":80},
    { "y": "8.", "a": 100, "b": 90,"c":30 },
    { "y": "9.", "a": 75,  "b": 65 ,"c":50},
    { "y": "10.", "a": 50,  "b": 40 ,"c":20},
    { "y": "11.", "a": 75,  "b": 65 ,"c":50},
    { "y": "12.", "a": 50,  "b": 40 ,"c":60}  
]
```

I am passing this json in variable 'yearly_total' dynamically.

Is there any way to show only selected lines? Please help me out...

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution. Check this fiddle...
 http://jsfiddle.net/4ztbu8oo/4/